# CSS property so that the text inside <div> element does not extend outside of background of <div>

Tags: css

What can I add to CSS property so that the text inside the div element does not extend out of my background color? I'm guessing that because the actual width of the div element is width of full page, so I will have to shrink my div element.

Please see example here

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/u5128tv7/)

```
<div class="test">sadfssdfjklsdfjklsdfsdfksdfkhsdfksdfkhsdfkhsdkhfsdhkfksdhkhsdfkhsdk</div>

.test {
background: grey;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario I use a combination of the below CSS.

`text-overflow: ellipsis` will give you an indication that the actually more text is present than what is shown (using an ellipsis (`...`) symbol).. `overflow: hidden` ensure that no content goes out of the parent boundary and `white-space: nowrap` ensures the text will stay in only one line.

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowarp;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

[jsfiddle.net/josangel555/6d0wz2Lc/](http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/6d0wz2Lc/)

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below CSS :

```
.test {
  background: grey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) says :

> The word-wrap property is used to specify whether or not the browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing box.

Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv96q0zx/) for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should add **overflow: auto;** along with **word-wrap: break-word;** to

```
.test {
background: grey;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
}
```

in case text inside div is more than the div size to allow scroll automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `word-wrap: break-word;` to your code.

```
.test {
    background: grey;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Here is an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5128tv7/1/) of your example.  Further, take a look at the `word-wrap` property [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) to understand why this method can be used and what over property values may be of use to you in the future.